Zywall USG 200 Internet Speed
I've a 1000 Mbps internet connection with a modem setup as bridge and internet ended in Zywall USG 200 device. Now, when I connect to the internet over LAN port of the Zywall, I can get only up to 200 Mbps speed.
Does it something with the device settings or the device can only support that much speed. If second, what type of feature for the new Zywall series I should be checking to get 1000 Mbps full internet speed.
Thanks.

sounds for me like a home and enduser equipment which is offtopic

Zywall USG is mostly used by small businesses. However, as described, the problem is impossible to solve on a Q/A site like this.

We use it in our small business where we have ~24 IP camera connected and smart home system. Where I can check to find the cause for this issue? This is the site I found when I search over google. Sorry for the inconvenience.
